# Can not alter column having Unique Constraint with Index using EF Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have a table called 'JobVendor' which has column called 'shortName'. This is part of Unique key constraint with Index on it.

```
        jobVendorBuilder.HasIndex(e => new { e.JobFk, e.ShortName }, "UQ_JobVendor_Job_shortName")
            .IsUnique();
```

I am trying to alter shortName length from 32 to 16 character using EF core fluent API.

```
        jobVendorBuilder.Property(e => e.ShortName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(16)
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

Add-Migration creates below code

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "ShortName",
            table: "JobVendor",
            type: "varchar(16)",
            unicode: false,
            maxLength: 16,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "varchar(32)",
            oldUnicode: false,
            oldMaxLength: 32);
```

But when tried to update Database, it throws below error...

> An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed on index 'JobVendor.UQ_JobVendor_Job_shortName'. It is being used for UNIQUE KEY constraint enforcement.

The SQL query that executed in the background...

```
DROP INDEX [UQ_JobVendor_Job_shortName] ON [JobVendor];
DECLARE @var0 sysname;
SELECT @var0 = [d].[name]
FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] 
= [c].[object_id]
WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[JobVendor]') AND [c].[name] = N'ShortName');
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [JobVendor] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [JobVendor] ALTER COLUMN [ShortName] varchar(16) NOT NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UQ_JobVendor_Job_shortName] ON [JobVendor] ([Job_FK], [ShortName]);
```

I am not sure why it is trying to drop index while altering column...

I have gone through couple of stack overflow questions and they suggested to drop index first and add later so I tried removing the Unique constraint and added migration. It added drop Index to migration explicitly

```
migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "UQ_JobVendor_Job_shortName",
            table: "JobVendor");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "ShortName",
            table: "JobVendor",
            type: "varchar(16)",
            unicode: false,
            maxLength: 16,
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "varchar(32)",
            oldUnicode: false,
            oldMaxLength: 32);
```

But trying to Update-Database still throws same error, as in this case too it is trying to drop index, which it is not able to do so...

```
Failed executing DbCommand (344ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', 
            CommandTimeout='30']
```

Internal SQL statement executed

```
    DROP INDEX [UQ_JobVendor_Job_shortName] ON [JobVendor];
```

Do I need to remove the column and add back to resolve this ? or any other better solution?

Comment: When you `ALTER` a column most of the time (there are a few exceptions, but we don't know the original definition) you need to `DROP` any `CONSTRAINT`s **and** `INDEX`es that the coln is in, and then recreate them. It srem the migration task is only doing half of that. The `CONSTRAINT` needs to be dropped first, then the `INDEX` and then finally be recreated.

Comment: Yes, That's what I tried in second method. Dropping Unique constraint and it's index with no luck, still It did throw same error.

Comment: Based on your code, I have created a sample, and use the related fluent API configuration, it seems that everything works well when using migration, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPM22.gif). You could consider changing the property length via [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/quickstarts/ssms-connect-query-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), open the table designer and change the property length, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJKuT.png), then update the database. Or execute a SQL query (change the string length) via SSMS.

Comment: @ZhiLv Thank you checking, the table that you created, does it have unique constraint on (JobVendor and ShortName)? I see only primary key. When I create Unique constraints , it adds index too and changing shortName length from fluent API tries to drop just the index and throws error as that index is being used by Unique Constraint.       I tried removing Constraint from SSMS and tried to update shortName, at that time it throws error saying "Trying to delete index which does not exists...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
migrationBuilder.DropUniqueConstraint(
        name: "UQ_JobVendor_Job_shortName",
        table: "JobVendor");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
        name: "ShortName",
        table: "JobVendor",
        type: "varchar(16)",
        unicode: false,
        maxLength: 16,
        nullable: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(string),
        oldType: "varchar(32)",
        oldUnicode: false,
        oldMaxLength: 32);
```

Comment: Do I need to add that 'DropUniqueConstraint' manually to migration? That is not generated while changing column length...

Comment: Thanks Sean, it led me to solution. EF core tries to create DropIndex(...) but that does not drop Unique Constarint. I changed DropIndex() to DropUniqueConstraint(..) and Added that back.